# Calculations with MySQL tables in real time

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL both with timeseries like:

- Table 1
- "time"    "open"  "high"  "low"   "close"
- "2014.01.15 00:20"    "1244.25"   "1244.28"   "1243.88"   "1243.91"
- "2014.01.15 00:15"    "1244.24"   "1244.36"   "1244.16"   "1244.22"
- "2014.01.15 00:10"    "1244.62"   "1244.63"   "1244.16"   "1244.21"
- Table 2
- "time"    "open"  "high"  "low"   "close"
- "2014.01.15 00:20"    "27.378"    "27.378"    "27.377"    "27.378"
- "2014.01.15 00:15"    "27.379"    "27.379"    "27.377"    "27.377"
- "2014.01.15 00:10"    "27.378"    "27.378"    "27.377"    "27.378"

Now, I need to create a 3rd table that will be created by multiplying relevant values.

- "2014.01.15 00:20" 1244.25*27.378   1244.28*27.378   1243.88*27.377   1243.91*27.378

So far it should not be difficult, but the issue is that both the tables are updating nearly in real-time - every few seconds. Not the whole table of course, but the latest row.

Now, how can I multiply the 2 original tables and create the new one that would be also updated with such a frequency - automatically every few seconds?

What approach would you suggest? Use cron, or?

BTW - sorry, not an IT guy. Need to find a general solution how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason why you can't make the two tables into a single table, and then just perform the calculations within the table when the row is updated?

Comment: probably you can use triggers

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: View - the  new table will be accessed by php to display it on web. I assumed it is better to calculate it once when genereting the new table than everytime when it is displayed on web.

Answer (score 0):

Your third table is entirely derived from your first two, so you can implement it as a query or a view.

```
 SELECT a.open*b.open AS open,
        a.high*b.high AS high,
        a.low *b.low  AS low,
        a.close*b.close AS close
   FROM table1 AS a
   JOIN table2 AS b ON a.time = b.time
```

It's not clear from your question why you need a separate table with actual data in it.

**edit**

Put indexes on the `time` columns of both tables.

If you want to retrieve only rows in, say, the last 24 hours, conclude the query with

```
 WHERE a.time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: All the tables are rather large - thousands of rows. With the last one updating nearly every second. The new table would be accessed by php to display on a website - the whole table. For load purpose reasons I assumed it would be better to do the calculations once - when creating the new table than every time when displaying the new one for each user on web.